# Best way to use conditional statement to require input

Tags: model-view-controller

I am developing an parking application and asking the user to input car data. If the state is not "WA", I want them to enter a VIN. Is the best place to do that on the client side or server? I've experimented with Data Annotations Requiredif in the model but it seems that only checks for null where I need to check for string value. Should I just put the conditional check in view and could you recommend the best way to do that? I'm getting better at this but still run into a roadblock now and then. Thanks!

Here is some of my code. In the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitVehicle", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { 
enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("ID")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonID, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Student or Staff ID number", autofocus = "autofocus" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PersonID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Plate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Plate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Plate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.State)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, 
    Parking.Models.DdlData.GetStatesList(), new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VIN)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VIN, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "VIN required if out of state vehicle" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VIN)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Make)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Make, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "e.g. Toyota" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Make, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
.... etc.
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add Vehicle</button>
```

Comment: "Best" is quite subjective. Typically, a belt-and-suspenders approach is called for: Only display a query if it's appropriate to do so on the frontend, **and also** validate that the data is present if-and-only-if it's expected on the backend. Keep in mind that in client-server architectures users can typically meddle in data returned from the frontend later, so it's unsafe to rely on anywhere deliberate tampering is a concern.

Comment: That said, this isn't a good StackOverflow question as currently asked. The "answerable" criteria in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic specifies that questions should actually have a canonical Right Answer; ideally, we want a narrow, specific question (whereas this doesn't even specify a language!). Broader design questions are typically a better fit for [softwareengineering.se] -- which is not to say that this would be acceptable there in its current form; the [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should be referenced.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the process. I specifically need to figure out the best way to require the VIN if the state is not 'WA'. I did check some other questions/answers but they tended to provide a solution to a null result rather than string. I thought the Data Annotations package would do it but still running into the same limits.